# Unable to insert record from stored procedure called from web service

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[omgbbq](
    [tbl_key] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [id] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_omgbbq] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [tbl_key] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

...and the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_omgwth 
    @name VARCHAR(10), 
    @id INT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO omgbbq (name, id) VALUES (@name, @id);
    SELECT MAX(tbl_key) AS Max_tbl_key FROM omgbbq;
END
```

I added a single record by calling the procedure from SSMS:

```
EXEC sp_omgwth 'Gareth', 2
```

and get

```
tbl_key,name,id
1,Gareth,2
```

So far, so good.  A colleague tries to call it from a web service and gets the return
'Max_tbl_key' 2

Also as expected.  However, the record does not appear in the table.  When I add a new record by calling the SP from SSMS, we see the following in the table:

```
tbl_key,name,id
1,Gareth,2
3,Gawain,4
```

It's like it added the record, which incremented the identity value, but then...I don't know, rolled it back or something.

Any ideas?  Both of us are connecting to the server as the same user, so it doesn't seem like it could be a credential permissions issue.  We are getting this same behavior from another table and another SP, which is why we created these two as tests.

Comment: You should **NOT EVER** use `SELECT MAX(tbl_key) ...` to get the value of an `IDENTITY` column - use `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()...` instead! Much safer - won't break in concurrency situations!

Comment: I should probably clarify that the developers traced the issue as far as they could.  They found that the SQL statement that was being passed worked perfectly fine when copied and pasted into SSMS.  Also, using the same code base to add a record via an INSERT statement also worked.  There seems to be something weird specifically about the webservice calling any stored procedure with an INSERT.

Comment: Agree with `marc's` comment above. You shouldn't use `MAX`. Please post your web service code. It being in a transaction that never gets committed sounds feasible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to find out what is happening in the database is to run a trace.  Run SQL Server Profiler and have a call to the web service to the stored procedure.  Then look at the events to find out what is happening.

That's a cryptic problem, but looking at a trace will tell you what and why.

Comment: Good thinking.  The trace shows that it was in fact inside a transaction that was rolled back:
`USE [tha_db]

go

BEGIN TRAN

go

exec sp_omgwtf 'matt', '2'

go

ROLLBACK TRAN

go

BEGIN TRAN

go`

Comment: The developers will look to see where their code might have done that tomorrow.  Thanks for all the ideas and pointers!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to provide an example of the SQL Client call from the webservice code.  You might try setting and checking the EXECUTE return status.

Comment: The client call is nothing particularly fancy, I don't have access to it but could get it if really needed.  I think the important point is that call works fine calling any stored procedure that does NOT have an INSERT in it.

Comment: Also, could you clarify what you mean by "setting and checking the EXECUTE return status"?