# Some MySQL queries don't take effect

Tags: mysql

I've written a python script that adds student data (name and classes) to a table one at a time. The table is structured so that there is a primary key column, a student name column, and then a column for each class. The script checks to see if the class it's adding already exists as a column, and if not it creates it. Then it writes 'true' under that column for the current student.

Here's my problem: from the log file I can see that every single query is sent to the database correctly, but some don't show up in the table. When I run these queries:

```
CREATE TABLE Students (idStudents INT NOT NULL, Name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (idStudents)) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
SET NAMES 'utf8'
INSERT INTO Students (idStudents, Name) VALUES ('1', 'Bror Tao Sjørslev Bojlen')
SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name='Students'
ALTER TABLE Students ADD 3ubmSL5 VARCHAR(20)
UPDATE Students SET 3ubmSL5='true' WHERE idStudents='1'
ALTER TABLE Students ADD 3uchSL3 VARCHAR(20)
UPDATE Students SET 3uchSL3='true' WHERE idStudents='1'
ALTER TABLE Students ADD 3udaBH3 VARCHAR(20)
UPDATE Students SET 3udaBH3='true' WHERE idStudents='1'
ALTER TABLE Students ADD 3uenA1H1 VARCHAR(20)
UPDATE Students SET 3uenA1H1='true' WHERE idStudents='1'
ALTER TABLE Students ADD 3umaHL4 VARCHAR(20)
UPDATE Students SET 3umaHL4='true' WHERE idStudents='1'
ALTER TABLE Students ADD 3uphH2 VARCHAR(20)
UPDATE Students SET 3uphH2='true' WHERE idStudents='1'
ALTER TABLE Students ADD 3uth1 VARCHAR(20)
UPDATE Students SET 3uth1='true' WHERE idStudents='1'
```

the table looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iZll.png).

That is, the final query

```
UPDATE Students SET 3uth1='true' WHERE idStudents='1'
```

doesn't go through.

I hope this makes sense, and someone can shed some light on this issue - it's driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the final statement is being rolled back.  I'm guessing that your client is wrapping the statements implicitly in a transaction.  I have seen specifically Navicat roll back transactions containing inserts or updates that aren't explicitly committed unless they are accompanied by another statement.  It's odd behavior, but I've watched it through a trace.

As an aside, your table design is rather unconventional.  Students and classes are distinct entities and should not be stored in the same table.  You are combining at least three different tables here; this will not scale well.

EDIT:

In fact, the first question I posted here involved this issue:
[Unable to insert record from stored procedure called from web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745665/unable-to-insert-record-from-stored-procedure-called-from-web-service)

I just remembered that. :)

Comment: Added a `COMMIT` query after each student and it fixed the issue - thanks! I appreciate the comment on the table structure, this is my first foray into programming and databases so any criticism is helpful. It's a very small project with maybe 100 rows, so scalability isn't an issue - but I'll find a better table design, to get into the habit of doing it properly!

Comment: Try a table for students, a table for classes, and then a table for enrollments.  The enrollments table might have nothing more than a StudentID column and a ClassID column.  When Student 1 enrolls in Class 3ubmSL5, the statement would be `INSERT INTO Enrollments (idStudent, idClass) VALUES (1, '3ubmSL5');`

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that out! I was considering something similar at first, but I decided against it because the Enrollments table would end up with the same student having a row for each of their classes. It "feels" weird for a single student to have multiple rows, but it does sound reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a problem with commiting updates to the database? I seem to recall that a couple of databases I've used have commited the changes from the previous query either when there's an explicit COMMIT or when you make a new query, so in this case, the final update wouldn't be commited when the script terminated, and the changes would be rolled back.

Comment: You're right, I had to add an explicit `COMMIT` query after each student. Strange, since it's a completely default database hosted locally. Thank you!